# Hibernate EJB architecture - Model ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, struts2, ejb

I'm trying to understand the basic architecture of a JavaEE achitecture working with Struts2, Hibernate and EJB.

I have a simple application which add employees and list them.

So far, I've made 3 projects in Eclipse:

- JPA project which contains my model linked to the database
- EJB project which handle service layer
- Dynamic web project for Struts 2

Dynamic web project > controller.EmployeeAction.java:

```
import local.EmployeeService;
import model.Employee;

public class EmployeeAction extends ActionSupport {    
    private Employee employee;
    private Collection<Employee> employeeList;

    @EJB
    private EmployeeService employeeManager;

    public String execute() {
        this.employeeList = employeeManager.findAll();
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String add() {
        employeeManager.addItem(this.employee);
        this.employeeList = employeeManager.findAll();
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    [...]
}
```

EJB Project > local.EmployeeService.java:

```
import model.Employee;

@Stateless
public class EmployeeService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

     public void addItem(Employee i) {
         em.persist(i);
     }

     public Collection<Employee> findAll() {
         Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e");
         return (Collection<Employee>) query.getResultList();
     }
}
```

JPA project > model.Employee:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"Employee\"")
@NamedQuery(name="Employee.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM Employee e")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Integer idemployee;

    @Column(length=255)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=255)
    private String username;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Integer getIdemployee() {
        return this.idemployee;
    }

    public void setIdemployee(Integer idemployee) {
        this.idemployee = idemployee;
    }

        [...]
}
```

But when I try to add an employee, I get a ClassNotFoundException for `model.Employee`.

The classpath seems good. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add your JPA proyect as dependency in your EJB proyect, and mark as Web Library Dependency in `Properties -> Java EE Module Dependencies`.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks, I've another issue, but this one is fixed. Just note that it's called `Deployment Assembly` in Eclipse Kepler.